# How to forbid punctuation and whitespace inside ngrams?

Tags: r, whitespace, n-gram, punctuation

I have a character vector like this:

```
sent <- c("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
          "Over the lazy dog jumped the quick brown fox.",
          "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")
```

and I am using `textcnt()` for generating bigrams as follows:

```
txt <- textcnt(sent, method = "string", split = " ", n=2, tolower = FALSE)
```

`format(txt)` gives me all bigrams

```
              frq rank  bytes Encoding
Over the      1   4.5   8     unknown
The quick     2   11.5  9     unknown
brown fox     2   11.5  9     unknown
brown fox.    1   4.5   10    unknown
dog jumped    1   4.5   10    unknown
dog. Over     1   4.5   9     unknown
fox jumps     2   11.5  9     unknown
fox. The      1   4.5   8     unknown
jumped the    1   4.5   10    unknown
jumps over    2   11.5  10    unknown
lazy dog      1   4.5   8     unknown
lazy dog.     2   11.5  9     unknown
over the      2   11.5  8     unknown
quick brown   3   15.5  11    unknown
the lazy      3   15.5  8     unknown
the quick     1   4.5   9     unknown
```

Real data has much more sentences. I have two questions:
1. Is it possible to mention that dot at the end of each sentence should be truncated in the resulting ngrams?
2. Is it possible prevent generation of ngrams that span on two sentences? `dog. Over` and `fox.  The`

Comment: What's you end goal? Depending on that, you could consider `library(quanteda); tokenize(sent, ngrams = 2L, removePunct = T)` or `library(quanteda);quanteda:dfm(sent, ngrams = 2L, removePunct = TRUE)` as an alternative. It get's you the bi-grams, cuts off puctuation chars, and does not merge the elements in `sent` to one sentence.

Comment: @lukeA the end goal is to rank bigrams using it's frequency as one of the metrics, thank you for pointing me to quanteda

Comment: @ImranAli, you're still not saying whether you want to allow/remove/selectively remove different punctuation symbols inside your n-grams. Please edit this into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid specific ngrams in **textcnt** by avoiding **texcnt**.  :-) To flesh out @lukeA's comment, here is the full **quanteda** solution.

```
require(quanteda)
packageVersion("quanteda")
## [1] ‘0.9.5.19’
```

This will do the tokenisation into bigrams, and remove punctuation at the same time. Because each sentence is a "document", bigrams will never span the documents.

```
(bigramToks <- tokenize(sent, ngrams = 2, removePunct = TRUE, concatenator = " "))
tokenizedText object from 3 documents.
## Component 1 :
## [1] "The quick"   "quick brown" "brown fox"   "fox jumps"   "jumps over"  "over the"    "the lazy"    "lazy dog"   
## 
## Component 2 :
## [1] "Over the"    "the lazy"    "lazy dog"    "dog jumped"  "jumped the"  "the quick"   "quick brown" "brown fox"  
## 
## Component 3 :
## [1] "The quick"   "quick brown" "brown fox"   "fox jumps"   "jumps over"  "over the"    "the lazy"    "lazy dog"
```

To get frequencies of these, you should tabulate the bigrams tokens by constructing a document-feature matrix using `dfm()`.  (Note: You could have skipped the tokenisation step and done this directly using `dfm(sent, ngrams = 2, toLower = FALSE, concatenator = " ")`.)

```
(bigramDfm <- dfm(bigramToks, toLower = FALSE, verbose = FALSE))
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 12 features.
## 3 x 12 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
##        features
## docs    The quick quick brown brown fox fox jumps jumps over over the the lazy lazy dog Over the dog jumped
##   text1         1           1         1         1          1        1        1        1        0          0
##   text2         0           1         1         0          0        0        1        1        1          1
##   text3         1           1         1         1          1        1        1        1        0          0
## features
## docs    jumped the the quick
##   text1          0         0
##   text2          1         1
##   text3          0         0

topfeatures(bigramDfm, n = nfeature(bigramDfm))
## quick brown   brown fox    the lazy    lazy dog   The quick   fox jumps  jumps over    over the    Over the 
##           3           3           3           3           2           2           2           2           1 
##  dog jumped  jumped the   the quick 
##           1           1           1
```